# How to Evaluate Dynamic Expressions Inside Angular Template (Angular version 12)

Tags: javascript, angular, expression

Dropdown component is required at some conditions and not required at other times. I'm currently using configuration to display all the fields, so I cannot hard code any values. validations are coming from server response how to evaluate dynamic expressions inside angular templates

```
<my-component-dropdown
   [options]="options"
   field="type"
   [isRequired]="config_Response.required"
 ></my-component-dropdown>
```

API Response

```
config_Response = {
  required: "(serverResponse.type === 'option 1')"
}
```

In TS

```
serverResponse = {
 type: 'option 1'
}
```

I used Eval it's working but I understood using eval create security issues. is there any other way to evaluate dynamic expressions

### HTML

```
[isRequired]="convertToExpression(config_Response.required)"
```

### TS

```
convertToExpression(value: string) {
 return eval(value)
}
```

Comment: The real question is, why is the APi giving such a strange reply? Why not just a boolean true/false?

Comment: My requirement is like that, app needs to run for multiple clients